# Create an account with web3.js v0.2.6

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ether

so everytime i try to create an account with web3 i always get errors like the wrong version of web3 and that i should switch to v1.0.0

i used this command to install web3

```
  npm install ethereum/web3.js --save
```

i ve tried these commands to create an account but there is always a mismatch

```
  web3.eth.accounts.create();
web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword')
.then(console.log);
```

and i always get errors even though i installed

```
npm install web3-eth-account --save 
npm install web3-eth-personal --save
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is

```
let a=web3.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword')
```

Comment: web3.js < v1.0 does not have the object `web3.personal`. See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API document.